# Using OAuth 2 with Retrofit Service Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, oauth-2.0, retrofit2

I am working on a project that uses Retrofit to connect to an external API. I am able to use Insomnia to successfully send and receive data to and from the API using the API and the provided OAuth 2 authentication method. I have put together the retrofit service I plan on using for this. However, have not been able to figure out how to add OAuth 2 to the service.

I am using Kotlin. minSdk = 24, targetSdk = 34

Could someone explain how I am supposed to do this?

I have done some basic Google searching, but a lot of the docs are 7+ years old and I am having trouble understanding how to covert their examples.